# MySQL, Selecting the index based on MIN timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to get the index of the row with the maximum timestamp. However, I can't seem to get just the index. Here's my code:

```
client.query('SELECT inde, MIN( stamp ) FROM archive', function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
});
```

'stamp' is my timestamp column. The above code will return one index AND the timestamp. BUT, when i switch from MIN to MAX, the printed timestamp does change to the max but the index remains the same (it returns the minimum index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting exactly what you asked for. All `inde` fields from the table, along with the overall global mininum for ALL records in that table.

To get only the record(s) associated with that minimum value, you need a slightly more complicated query:

```
SELECT *
FROM archive
WHERE stamp = (SELECT MIN(stamp) FROM archive)
```